# Horizontal ListView.builder and vertical ListView.builder within the same column

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to have a horizontal scrolling feed at the top, along with a vertical scrolling feed below. When I add the vertical `ListView.builder` below the horizontal one inside the `SingleChildScrollView` it gives me `vertical viewport was given unbound height` error.

Feed screen: Works properly if I manually add the `VerticalFeedItem`'s like so. But, obviously this will be an undefined length of widgets so `ListView.builder` is what I'm looking to use.

```
class MyFeed extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyFeed({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black12),
            // margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: HorizontalScrollView(),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .40,
          ),
          WhatsNewHeading(),
          VerticalFeedItem(),                        //Works
          VerticalFeedItem(),
          VerticalFeedItem(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Feed Screen: doesn't work

```
class MyFeed extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyFeed({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black12),
            // margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: HorizontalScrollView(),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .40,
          ),
          WhatsNewHeading(),
          VerticalFeed(),                       //Doesn't work
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Vertical feed:

```
class VerticalFeed extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 4,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => VerticalFeedItem(),
    );
  }
}
```

Horizontal feed:

```
class HorizontalScrollView extends StatelessWidget {
  final articles = DUMMY_ARTICLES;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ArticleItem(
        article: articles[i].article,
        imageUrl: articles[i].imageUrl,
        id: articles[i].id,
        heading: articles[i].heading,
        capability: articles[i].capability,
        dateTime: DateTime.now(),
      ),
      itemCount: articles.length,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add one properties of Listview.Builder
like

```
ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemBuilder: (c,i)
  {
    return Text("ada");
  },
);
```

Add shrinkWrap:true in both of your listview builder

Comment: This only sort of works. It does render, but i cant vertically scroll while pressing on a list item. only from above a list item in the heading or in the horizontal list.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap VerticalFeed and HorizontalScrollView with **Expanded** widget.

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black12),
      // margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      child: HorizontalScrollView(),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .40,
    ),
    Expanded(child: WhatsNewHeading()),
    Expanded(child: VerticalFeed()),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your horizontal listview and vertical listview in two **Expanded** widgets. I had the same problem and here is an exemple of my code where it works perfectly:

```
  Scaffold(
   body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: <Widget>[
          Your Widgets, 
          ],),), 
        Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
          Your Widgets, 
          ],),),]),);
```